# Parallel pipeline with 2 inline stages

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-blueocean

Playing with Jenkins pipeline from https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/examples/#parallel-multiple-nodes

#### Simple two parallel steps (OK)

I made a first test pipeline this way:

```
pipeline {
   stages {
      stage('Build') {
         steps {
            script {
                def labels = ['precise', 'trusty'] // labels for Jenkins node types we will build on
                def builders = [:]
                for (x in labels) {
                    def label = x // Need to bind the label variable before the closure - can't do 'for (label in labels)'
                
                    // Create a map to pass in to the 'parallel' step so we can fire all the builds at once
                    builders[label] = {
                        node('JenkinsNode') {
                           sh script: 'echo build', label: 'Build on $env.NODE_NAME'
                        }
                    }
                }
                parallel builders
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

It resulted in the following expected diagram in Blue Ocean view:

[image]

#### Simple two parallel steps with two sub steps each (KO)

##### Attempt#1

Then I tried to split each parallel step in two inline stages (to simulate build and tests for example)

```
pipeline {
   stages {
      stage('Build') {
         steps {
            script {
                def labels = ['precise', 'trusty'] // labels for Jenkins node types we will build on
                def builders = [:]
                for (x in labels) {
                    def label = x // Need to bind the label variable before the closure - can't do 'for (label in labels)'
                
                    // Create a map to pass in to the 'parallel' step so we can fire all the builds at once
                    builders[label] = {
                        node('JenkinsNode') {
                            stage("build") {
                                sh script: 'echo build', label: 'Build on $env.NODE_NAME'
                            }
                            stage("test") {
                                sh script: 'echo run unit tests', label: 'Run unit tests on $env.NODE_NAME'
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                parallel builders
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

The Jenkins logs show both `build` and `test` stages are run for each parallel step, but the Blue Ocean view only states `build` stage:

[image]

I would expect something like:

[image]

I'm not very clear about the boundaries between declarative and scripted pipelines, but I suspect a misunderstanding around this.

##### Attempt#2

Following a suggestion in comments, I slightly changed the code to have sub-stages unique names (`build1`, `test1`, `build2`, `test2`) and it does not change the diagram. I still have build steps only.

[image]

Here are the Jenkins logs in this case:

[image]

***Question***: Is the pipeline invalid (leading to only "build" sub-steps instead of `build` + `test` sub-steps) or is it a limitation of Blue Ocean (1.25.3)?

Comment: You have some code and images, but what is your question?

Comment: Question updated. Is it more clear now?

Comment: You are overriding the default label for each stage with a custom identical label for both, so Blue Ocean would aggregate both of the stages into a single label. If you can confirm in the logs that both nested stages complete successfully, then that would be the root cause here.

Comment: I slightly adapted the code so that names are unique (see attempt#2). Parallel branches keys were already unique (don't be fooled by `builders[label]` and `def label = x` used for scope protection) and now each stage name of each branch is unique too. But it does not solve this issue apparently.

Comment: Is there any reason you're building parallel stages in script and not using the declarative syntax? I have this successfully working with declarative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When combining declarative and scripted syntax things become a bit tricky.
In this specific combination case, to make it work like you expect you must create an encapsulating stage for each parallel execution code that has the same name as the parallel branch.
This will cause the blue ocean to display the inner stages as requested.

```groovy
pipeline {
   agent any
   stages {
      stage('Build') {
         steps {
            script {
                def labels = ['precise', 'trusty']
                def builders = [:]
                for (x in labels) {
                    def label = x 
                    builders[label] = {
                        stage(label) { // Encapsulating stage with same name as parallel branch
                           node('JenkinsNode') {
                               stage("build") {
                                   sh script: 'echo build', label: 'Build on $env.NODE_NAME'
                               }
                               stage("test") {
                                   sh script: 'echo run unit tests', label: 'Run unit tests on $env.NODE_NAME'
                               }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                parallel builders
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Or in a more Groovy way:

```groovy
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def labels = ['precise', 'trusty']
                    def builders = labels.collectEntries {
                        ["${it}" : {
                            stage(it) { // Encapsulating stage with same name as parallel branch
                                node('JenkinsNode') {
                                    stage("build") {
                                        sh script: 'echo build', label: 'Build on $env.NODE_NAME'
                                    }
                                    stage("test") {
                                        sh script: 'echo run unit tests', label: 'Run unit tests on $env.NODE_NAME'
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                    parallel builders
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The result:

[image: and the result:]